# Find the intersection of two lists of objects by using a comparison function

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

### tl;dr:

I have two lists of class objects in Python (both are the same type), and when comparing them, I need to identify objects that exists in both lists by comparing them using a function that returns `True` or `False`.

I need to compare a car's tires to determine *if the tire is a match* ("it'll fit"), and sometimes if a tire is *identical* (same brand/make/year).

> Given the example below, how can I compare the car's current tires to a list of potential tires I got back from the previous `find` call using the `compare.is_exact_match` function?

I've seen similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879991/intersection-of-two-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-a-key) which lets me compare objects based on the value of a property, but I'm not sure if (how) this same method could work for a function comparison.

### The details:

I have a `Car`, and one of its properties is a set of tires (subclass `Tire`):

```
def Car:
    def __init__(self, ...args):
         self.make = make
         self.model = model
         self.year = year
         self.trim = trim
         self.color = color
         self.vin = vin
         self.tires: [Tire] = tires
         self.potential_matches: [Tire] = []

    def Tire:
        def __init__(self, ...args):
            self.brand = brand
            self.model_number = model_number
            self.year = year
            self.diameter = diameter
            self.width = width
            self.sidewall = sidewall
            self.circumference = self.circumference
            self.revs_per_mile = self.revs_per_mile
```

I have some a somewhat complicated heuristic that compares lists of cars to find matching tires for this car. This is a mock example, but let's assume this is a tire swapping marketplace so you understand how we go there. In this theoretical product, tire data in the marketplace is often incomplete. Determining if a tire is a match is expensive, so we do some prework to reduce that footprint. Once we have that, we often need to *further* compare tires to differentiate between "just a match" and "an identical tire".

This looks something like:

```
@classmethod
def find(cls, car: Car, marketplace_cars: [Car]) -> [Car.Tire]:
    matches = list(filter(lambda c:
         # One thing we can try is comparing the car first. If the car is a match,
         # the tires probably are too.
         car.make == c.make
         and car.model == c.model
         and car.year == c.year
         and car.trim == c.trim

         # If any of those fail, run the expensive heuristic
         and compare.is_match(car, c)
    marketplace_cars))

    # Extract a list of tires from the list of cars that were identified as having matches
    matching_tires = list(itertools.chain(*[m.tires for m in matches]))

    return matching_tires
```

Now from this list, we want to further narrow it down to show any tires that are *identical* matches. This means comparing make, model, and mileage as well as all the other stuff in the first comparison. The `compare.is_exact_match` takes individual `Tire` objects this time and compares them.

And this is where I'm lost:

> How can I compare the car's current tires to a list of potential tires I got back from the previous `find` call using the `compare.is_exact_match` function?

```
@classmethod
def find_exact(cls, car: Car) -> [Car.Tire]:

    # Pseudo code, because what do I do here?
    # Should/can I do this with sets, or?
    exact_matches = list(filter(
                          lambda tire, match: compare.is_exact_match(tire, match), 
                          (car.tires, car.potential_matches)))

    # Returns an array of [Car.Tire] that are exact matches
    return exact_matches
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom hash function that only contains the variables that you want to match? Then you can quickly check if the tires are matching by verifying that the hashes are equal. This can also be done with the `__eq__` in the `Tire` class. Then you can use `tire == match`.

Comment: That's a cool idea. What would that look like? I don't see any questions around that give an example for my use case, but maybe I'm not searching for the right thing.

Comment: I think [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) would work for you. For an example see the Talk from Raymon Hettinger ([link](https://youtu.be/T-TwcmT6Rcw?t=2029)). The other option is to override the custom [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) or use a custom [\_\_eq__](https://hynek.me/articles/hashes-and-equality/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was really overthinking this, and a simple list comprehension was all I needed.

```
@classmethod
def find_exact(cls, car: Car) -> [Car.Tire]:

    exact_matches = [m for t in car.tires for m in car.potential_matches if compare.is_exact_match(t, m)]
    """
    for t in car.tires:
        for m in car.potential_matches:
            if compare.is_exact_match(t, m):
                m
    """

    # Returns an array of [Car.Tire] that are exact matches
    return exact_matches
```